# Creating activity to open YouTube and search automaticlly

Tags: java, android

so I wasn't sure how to put this in the title, but what I have been trying to do is making my application open, lets say YouTube and then enter a search automaticlly (given previously). Here is my code which makes it easier to explain.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Get the URL and search from the intent
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

    // Open browser and auto search in searchbar
    if (!message.startsWith("http://") && !message.startsWith("https://"))
    message = "http://" + message + ".com";
    Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(message));
    startActivity(browserIntent);
}
```

So What I wanted to do was open up YouTube (this works fine), however I want to use the next words put into the search (split with a space) to be typed into the searchbar in YouTube.

1. What you enter: Youtube funny videos
2. Delivers message into the second activity: opens the URL "Youtube" (works fine so far)
3. The activity recognizes the other parts of message after "Youtube" (split with space) and puts these into the search bar in YouTube.

How can I do this?

Comment: Hmmm..not sure if this is possible without some sort of API, but I am curious to see this answer as well!

Comment: I know that I can make it using two different Intents.... because YouTube has its own link for searching, and I can use that for opening my search. However, I want to know if I can split up my code into two with a space. Here is how it would go if I used the same Intent for both functions. This is what my URL would look like = https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=youtube ..... @JadeByfield

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, what you want to do is you want to extract from a string `"youtube cat videos"` parts `"youtube"` and `"cat videos"`. The following code does that:

```
String message = "youtube cat videos";
// Remove leading and trailing whitespaces.
message = message.trim();  
// Set limit to one so only the first  space is used to split.
String[] parts = message.split(" ", 2);  
// Check if domain and query are set.
if (parts.length < 2) {
    // Invalid.
}
String domain = parts[0];  
String query = parts[1];  
// Check if we have a valid domain name.
if (domain.matches("[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]+")) {
    // Do stuff.
}
```

Don't forget the trim() and matches() functions to filter out invalid queries.

Comment: I can't get your code working.... it just makes my application crash, where should I add the code I ahve allready written, and what parts of it should I keep? @Nutomic

Comment: I actually got the split() call wrong and missed a closing quote, tested it now and it works.

Comment: So what part of my code do I add in the Do stuff section? Because I'm not sure how I can use the use http code thing in this code.... @Nutomic

Comment: You can do `String url = "http://" + domain + ".com" + "/results?search_query=" + query.replace(" ", "+");` and then pass that to your Intent (using Uri.parse).